# Finding specific string and printing from collected data of a site using python

Tags: python, string, web

Here, i am trying to do that, i have a data from ngrok tunnel (http://127.0.0.1//api/tunnels) and i want to print only 'public_url' : 'https://.....ngrok.io' which i have collected from that site, that data looks like this

`{'tunnels': [{'name': 'command_line', 'uri': '/api/tunnels/command_line', 'public_url': 'https://a28e4c77.ngrok.io', 'proto': 'https', 'config': {'addr': 'http://localhost:80', 'inspect': True}....`Something more

This is the part of that data.
I have use this code to collect that data.

```
import requests 
url = "http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
```

I have also save this into a ngrok.txt but i have absolutely no idea to find...To write this data i use this code : -

```
import requests
url = "http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
f = open('ngrok.txt', 'w')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your json string to a json object. You can do it with function `loads()` from `json` library.

Here the code for your example:

```
import json
json.loads(data)["tunnels"][0]["public_url"]
```

- `json.loads(data)` converts a string to a json object
- `["tunnels"]` gets the object associated with the name "tunnels"
- The resulting object is a list, indeed you need to get the first element with `[0]`
- Finally you get `"public_url"`

Comment: @Adarsh please if this answer is what you was looking for upvote and select it as correct answer in order to let future readers learn something new from your question. Thank you